# run method for a given time - or until a condition is met

Tags: java

I want a method to recieve TimeUnit object (any) , and long timeout .

the method should return true if during this time something happened (-not relevant) or false otherwise ,

**the method should not sleep for the time given and then test if condition was met - but to continue testing condition until the required time passed or condition met**

```
public static boolean checkTimeOut(TimeUnit unit ,long timeout){
    // wait based on TimeUnit and timeout
    if(/*condition met*/){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TimeUnit testingMinutes = TimeUnit.valueOf("MINUTES");
    TimeUnit testingSeconds = TimeUnit.valueOf("SECONDS");
    TimeUnit testingMilli = TimeUnit.valueOf("MILLISECONDS");
    checkTimeOut(testingMinutes , 1);
    checkTimeOut(testingSeconds, 200);
    checkTimeOut(testingMilli, 500);
}
```

*this code is used only as example of general structure ,and not part of the actual project.*

Comment: have you looked at locks?

Answer (score 0):

Without further details, a `while` loop seems to be the tool for this job:

```java
public static boolean checkTimeOut(TimeUnit unit ,long timeout){
    long limit = unit.toMillis(timeout);
    long now = Clock.systemDefaultZone().millis();
    while(Clock.systemDefaultZone().millis() <= now + limit) {
        if (/* condition */) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

By the way, instead of using `valueOf()`, you could simple use one of the `Enum` available, so that

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TimeUnit testingMinutes = TimeUnit.MINUTES;
    TimeUnit testingSeconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS;
    TimeUnit testingMilli = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS;
    checkTimeOut(testingMinutes , 1);
    checkTimeOut(testingSeconds, 200);
    checkTimeOut(testingMilli, 500);
}
```